# Duda para mostrar link en FPDF

Tags: php

Buenas tardes:
Tengo el siguiente Código PHP y estoy usando la librería FPDF

```
while($productos2 = mysql_fetch_array($productos)){
$item = $item+1;    
$pdf->Cell(5, 8 ,$item, 1);
$pdf->Cell(10, 8 ,$productos2['FOLIO'], 1);
$pdf->Cell(70, 8 ,$productos2['NOMBRE'], 1);
$pdf->Cell(25, 8 ,date("d-m-Y",strtotime($productos2['FECHA_SOLICITUD'])), 1);
$pdf->Cell(25, 8 ,$productos2['TIPO_AUTORIZACION'], 1);
$pdf->Cell(25, 8 ,date("d-m-Y",strtotime($productos2['FECHA_AUTORIZACION'])), 1);
$pdf->Cell(20,8 , '<a href="http://www.gb.intragruver.com/mb/rprh06/final.php?folio=$productos2["FOLIO"]" target="_blank">Enlace</a>',1); 
$pdf->Ln(8);
```

Deseo que al final me muestre en la ultima columna el link o enlace para dar click e ir a esa pagina. El problema es que no se cual es la sintaxis correcta. Ya le estuve quitando las comillas simples por dobles y nada.

Esto es lo que me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al pasar el puntero sobre el link me sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo que cuando le de clic me mande a la pagina que hace referencia al folio

¿Podrían ayudarme de favor? Gracias

Comment: ¿Has visitado la doc oficial? Ahí viene muy bien explicado y hasta un demo, http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm

Comment: Si lo revise pero el link que veo ahi hace referencia a otra pagina dentro del mismo documento. Lo que yo necesito es que se vea "Dar Click Aqui" en vez de que coloque todo el a href y a ultimas no muestre nada

Comment: Puedes aplicar lo mismo, al fin de cuentas es un href y en el demo que te muestran dice "click here", pero en fin....

Comment: @x4mp73r No me funciona. Ya lo intente y no lo hace.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell(1,0,"Acepto las condiciones del servicio y la");

Cell(46,0,utf8_decode("política de privacidad y tratamiento de datos personales"),0,0,0,false,'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hola_mundo');
Cell(20,0,"de una empresa muy loquilla.");
```

En este caso puedes solamente usar un cell el cual sería el del medio
`Cell(46,0,utf8_decode("política de privacidad y tratamiento de datos personales"),0,0,0,false,'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hola_mundo');`
y solo reemplaza el mensaje solo que no mostrará el link sino que redirigirá a la pagina es decir debes tener el botón ctrl para que te redirija a la pagina que esperas sin tener que salir de tu documento de pdf.

Answer (score -1):

```
$link = 'http://www.fpdf.org/';

$pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Titulo', 1, 1,'C', true, $link);
```